# poll() method not working in Linux but working in Mac

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I am using C++ code snippet for port forwarding. The requirement is to do the hand shake between two ports. It should be two way communication. That is to forward what ever iscoming on the source port to destination port. And then to forward the response of the destination port to the source port.

This piece of code is working as expected on my mac system. But when I am running this code on Linux system I am facing one issue.

Issue:

The C++ code that I am using is having 3 parts:

1. `establish_connection_to_source();`
2. `open_connection_to_destination();`
3. `processconnetion();`

On Linux: establish_connection_to_source();  and open_connection_to_destination(); is working perfectly fine. But processconnetion(); is havng one issue.

Following is the process connection method:

```
void processconnetion()
{
    buffer *todest  = new buffer(socket_list[e_source].fd,socket_list[e_dest].fd);
    buffer *tosrc   = new buffer(socket_list[e_dest].fd,socket_list[e_source].fd);

    if (todest == NULL || tosrc == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"out of mememory\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    unsigned int loopcnt;
    profilecommuncation srcprofile(COMM_BUFSIZE);
    profilecommuncation destprofile(COMM_BUFSIZE);

    while (true) {
        int withevent = poll(socket_list, 2, -1);
        loopcnt++;
        fprintf(stderr,"loopcnt %d socketswith events = %d source:0x%x dest:0x%x\n", loopcnt, withevent, socket_list[e_source].revents, socket_list[e_dest].revents);
        if ((socket_list[e_source].revents | socket_list[e_dest].revents) & (POLLHUP | POLLERR)) {
            // one of the connections has a problem or has Hungup
            fprintf(stderr,"socket_list[e_source].revents= 0x%X\n", socket_list[e_source].revents);
            fprintf(stderr,"socket_list[e_dest].revents= 0x%X\n", socket_list[e_dest].revents);
            fprintf(stderr,"POLLHUP= 0x%X\n", POLLHUP);
            fprintf(stderr,"POLLERR= 0x%X\n", POLLERR);
            int result;
            socklen_t result_len = sizeof(result);
            getsockopt(socket_list[e_dest].fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &result, &result_len);
            fprintf(stderr, "result = %d\n", result);
            fprintf(stderr,"exiting as one connection had an issue\n");
            break;
        }
        if (socket_list[e_source].revents & POLLIN) {
            srcprofile.increment_size(todest->copydata());
        }
        if (socket_list[e_dest].revents & POLLIN) {
            destprofile.increment_size(tosrc->copydata());
        }
    }
    delete todest;
    delete tosrc;
    close(socket_list[e_source].fd);
    close(socket_list[e_dest].fd);
    srcprofile.dumpseensizes("source");
    destprofile.dumpseensizes("destination");
}
```

Here it is giving error - `exiting as one connection had an issue` that means that `if ((socket_list[e_source].revents | socket_list[e_dest].revents) & (POLLHUP | POLLERR))` is returning `true`. The issue is with the destination port and not in case of source.

Note:
Variales used in the `processconnetion();` method:
`socket_list` is a structure of type `pollfd`. Following is the description:

```
struct pollfd {
    int     fd;
    short   events;
    short   revents;
};

pollfd socket_list[3];


#define     e_source    0
#define     e_dest      1
#define     e_listen    2
```

Following is the output at the time for exit:

```
   connecting to destination:  destination IP / 32001.
   connected...
   loopcnt 1 socketswith events = 1 source:0x0 dest:0x10
   socket_list[e_source].revents= 0x0
   socket_list[e_dest].revents= 0x10
   POLLHUP= 0x10
   POLLERR= 0x8
   result = 0
   exiting as one connection had an issue
```

`int withevent = poll(socket_list, 2, -1);` here the withevent value returned is `1`

Socket List Initialisation:

```
guard( (socket_list[e_listen].fd = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP )), "Failed to create socket listen, error: %s\n", "created listen socket");

 void guard(int n, char *msg, char *success)
{
    if (n < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, msg, strerror(errno) );
        exit(-1);
    }
    fprintf(stderr,"n = %d %s\n",n, success);

}
```

I am not able to figure out the issue as it is working fine in mac. Any leads why this behaviour in Linux is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start with determining which of the connections had an issue, and what the issue was.

Comment: @molbdnilo it's with Destination

Comment: maybe it's unrelated but `loopcnt` is not initialised.

Comment: And the issue was? Error code? You can't seriously expect to get help when you omit all the useful information.

Comment: So what is the problem with the destination, is it a hang up or an error? What happens on the destination side, have you checked there?

Comment: how did you initialise `socket_list` before calling `poll()`?

Comment: Also note that `POLLHUP` can happen even if there's data left to read from the other end. The safest way to receive all data and detect a nicely closed connection on a TCP socket or a pipe is to `read` or `recv` until either function returns `0`. You might also need to call `read` or `recv` to get the actual error of the descriptor in the event of `POLLERR`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't use `new` and `delete` for your `buffer` objects. I don't see any need for that.

Comment: @user207421 I have updated the question with the state of different variable. Please have a look.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @prog-fh loop count is getting initialised. Check the log I just added. Socket list initialisation is also added.

Comment: You have not updated your question with any value of `errno` or `SO_ERROR`, which at present is the only thing of interest. Voted to close.

Comment: @IshanTiwary your « log » does not show **how** `loopcnt` and `socket_list` are initialised. It just shows that **by chance** the uninitialised bytes of `loopcnt` are all zeroes, but says nothing about the initial values of `fd` and `events` in `socket_list`.

Comment: @user207421 are you pointing to POLLHUP. socket_list[e_dest].revents= 0x10 and 
POLLHUP= 0x10. I don't see any errno. I think poll doesn't set errno when it returns a positive number. On success, a positive number is returned; this number is the number of structures which have a nonzero revents fields. A value of 0 indicates that the call timed out. On error, -1 is returned and errno is set. But since poll returned  1, errno is not set.

Comment: Every socket has a SO_ERROR property. I;'ve already mentioned it. When people tell me about things I look them up.

Comment: @user207421 I have used getsockopt() to get the SO_ERROR value. It is 0. I have updated the code and the result in question also.

Comment: So one of `(socket_list[e_source]` or `socket_list[e_dest]` got an error and you only fetched SO_ERROR for one of them and it was zero. So you should fetch it for the other one, right? And print it out as `SO_ERROR`, not `result`, so everybody knows what you're talking about, including yourself. This is all rather basic.